# python with two iterators increment one at a time

Tags: python, linked-list, iterator, mergesort

I am a newbie in python.

I tried implementing something like merge sort in python. I used singly linked list from https://pythonhosted.org/llist/#sllist-objects. To merge two sorted list, i need to traverse both lists with iterator. The pseudo code looks something like:

```
n3 = sllist()
for n1 in list1 and n2 in list2:
    if (n1 > n2):
        n3.append(n1)
        n1++               # c way of doing thing
    else:
        n3.append(n2)
        n2++               # c way of doing thing
```

But I don't know how to make this working in python. Any pointer or hint will help.

Edit:
After all the discussions and suggestions, I came up with code something like this. Can anyone tell me, how to get rid of last two while loops. I was planning to use "extend" but unable to use it.

```
final_list = sllist()
node1 = list1.first
node2 = list2.first

while node1 and node2:
    if node1.value < node2.value:
        final_list.append(node1)
        node1 = node1.next              
    else:
        final_list.append(node2)
        node2 = node2.next
while node1:
    final_list.append(node1)
    node1 = node1.next
while node2:
    final_list.append(node2)
    node2 = node2.next

return final_list
```

Comment: See `more_itertools.collate` [here](https://pythonhosted.org/more-itertools/api.html).

Comment: Something like `[a if a > b else b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JoelCornett: did you try it?  It doesn't work.

Comment: @NeilG: Yup, these are definitely not the droids I'm looking for...

Answer (score 3):

I generally do this with iterables and `next`:

```
lst1 = iter(list1)
lst2 = iter(list2)
out = sllist()
sentinel = object()
n1 = next(lst1, sentinel)
n2 = next(lst2, sentinel)
while n1 is not sentinel and n2 is not sentinel:
    if n1 > n2:
        out.append(n2)
        n2 = next(lst2, sentinel)
    elif n2 >= n1:
        out.append(n1)
        n1 = next(lst1, sentinel)
out.extend(lst1)
out.extend(lst2)
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you could also write it as:

```
lst1 = iter(list1)
lst2 = iter(list2)
out = sllist()
try:
    n1 = next(lst1)
    n2 = next(lst2)
    while True:
        if n1 > n2:
            out.append(n2)
            n2 = next(lst2)
        elif n2 >= n1:
            out.append(n1)
            n1 = next(lst1)

except StopIteration:  # raised when next(...) fails.
    out.extend(lst1)
    out.extend(lst2)
```

It's functionally equivalent.  Take your pick of whichever you like better :-)

Comment: why not replace sentinel with `try`/`except`?

Comment: @NeilG because I use it in 4 places -- that's a lot of exception handling . . .

Comment: I think you can surround the whole thing in one try/except?

Comment: I suppose you're right -- There aren't too many other things in the while loop that could raise `StopIteration` ...

Comment: Trying to do it myself, I guess your solution is about as nice.

Comment: Since I have come from C++ and generally python code used to be much cleaner. But I feel other way around for this particular code.

Comment: @user3368154 -- Yeah, I've written this function *LOTS* of times and I don't feel like the C way is much cleaner -- But generally we tend to hold python to a higher bar of cleanliness.  In this case I think they're roughly equal.  However, I will say that doing it this way in python allows you to merge arbitrary iterables.  Change the `appends` and `extends` to the approprite `yield` and `yield from` and you can merge sorted iterables of infinite length (or at least part of them :-)

Comment: I have modified my initial post. Check once if it can be cleaned more.

Answer (score 1):

Well the way you are doing it you need indexs

so:

```
while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
  if list1[i] > list2[j]:
    n3.append(list1[i])
    i+=1
  else:
    n3.append(list2[j])
    j+=1

n3.extend(list1[i:])
n3.extend(list2[j:])
```

Comment: You need to check if `i` or `j` is less than the length of their respective lists after the loop to merge the remaining elements.

Comment: True, I shall fix that

Comment: Just `n3.extend(list1[i:])`, use `+=` instead of `++`, and fix for PEP08?

Comment: +1, I hope you don't mind my tidying up your code according to PEP8.

Comment: No I do not as a matter of fact I appreciate it :D